# Hi, how can i add classpath in android studio last version?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

this is buil.gradle proyect, then of a update i don't know how to add classpath

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what my build.gradle looks like

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
       
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Hope this helped.